# jquery function needs to check id is not empty in each ul

Tags: jquery

I have this expression `$('ul[id]').each(function())`. I need it to say that the id is not empty rather than anything. What is the proper way to code this?

Check out this sample http://jsfiddle.net/QhLu5/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to select all `ul` elements that have an `id` that is not an empty string, you could use `filter()`:

```
var ulElementsWithID = $('ul[id]').filter(function(){ return this.id.length; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a correct way of doing it. You are targeting `ul` which has the `id` attribute using `ul[id]` selector.

If you don't want empty ids, then use:

```
$('ul[id]').filter(function(){ return this.id != "" });
```